# Not able to connect to mongodb server on google compute engine through my java code from my local machine

Tags: java, mongodb, google-compute-engine

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("23.236.50.143",27017);
    System.out.print(mongo);
    List<String> dbs = mongo.getDatabaseNames();
    for(String db1 : dbs){
        System.out.println(db1);
}
```

23.236.50.143 is the external ip of the compute engine instance.

I have also added firewall rule to allow connection on port number 27017.

Still `Connection Refused Error` is coming.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue ? Usually "connection refused" means that the packets are getting to the server but they are blocked by the firewall or there is no service running on that port. Try to see if mongo is even using that port locally : $ sudo netstat  -tulnp | grep 27017

Comment: After `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 27017` proved that the service was running, all I had to do was setup the firewall rule in the `network` which the mongodb instances were deployed on:
`Source filter Allow from any source (0.0.0.0/0)` `Allowed protocols and ports tcp:27017 udp:27017` `Target tags: mongodb`

Answer (score 3):

You have mentioned that you have added firewall rule to allow connection on port 27017. Make sure that you added this firewall rule in the `Google Cloud Console` dashboard or using `gcloud` command line utility.

After setting this, note the Internal IP of the compute engine instance, which is usually mentioned in the `Google Cloud Console` dahsboard.

Edit the Mongo config file (usually present at `/etc/mongod.conf`) to add the Internal IP of the compute engine instance in the `bind_ip` variable.

The config file will look like this:

```
$ vim /etc/mongod.conf
# /etc/mongod.conf

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

After adding your Internal IP, the config file will look like this:

```
$ vim /etc/mongod.conf

# /etc/mongod.conf

# Listen to local and LAN interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,X.X.X.X
```

where `X.X.X.X` is the Internal IP of your instance. Save the file and restart mongo server.

**Note:** Don't use the External IP in the mongo config file.

**Reference:** [MKyong.com : MongoDB – Allow remote access](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/)